# Android - How can I get a link in an email to open in my android application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So, I am sending links via email from my application. When these are received by another user, I would like the link to be able to open directly in my Android application.

Have been trying to achieve this by using Intents but currently cannot get working correctly.

Comment: You need to enable deep linking in your app. You can get more information https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Comment: What I am trying to do is, the user is trying to access https://www.apple.com/ for example - how would the intent filters be set up as could be a different URL each time.